# remove the first background color for button

Tags: html, css

"ADD TO CART" & "save design" button is displaying like below image.

I wanted to display "SAVE DESIGN" button as like "ADD TO CART"

means i want to remove first background-color also that dot symbol.

**"code for add to cart"**

```
.product-view .add-to-cart-buttons .button {
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    line-height: 35px;
    min-height: 35px;
    min-width: 120px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**code for "save design"**

```
#aitcg-control-panel {

    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    bottom: 107px;
    z-index: 1; 
    padding: 5px !important;
    background:#ff7704;

}
```

[image]

when i used same css that we applied for "ADD TO CART" button, but it did't worked for me.

**demo link** : please visit [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) , you can see "ADD TO CART & SAVE DESIGN" section at middle of the page.

Comment: We are going to need your HTML structure in order to help you.

Comment: Getting crazy, but you have to copy exactly the structure of HTML of first one and copy it twice. In the second one, just change the inner text...

Comment: @MitchelJager as we are using magento site its combination of lot of html & php codes, so its very difficult to create  snippet also to find the html code that is result for displaying those buttons, i will try to update the question with html code.

Comment: @EliasMP as we are using magento site its combination of lot of html & php codes, so its very difficult to create  snippet also to find the html code that is result for displaying those buttons, i will try to update the question with html code.

Comment: "add to cart" is a button but "save design" is a div with a button inside, you have to edit `aitcg-button` class for remove the border and brackground

Comment: @blonfu please post an answer with code.

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe You do not need exact code, just isolate the HTML and CSS and post it here. Makes it much easier for people to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this style in stylesheet

```
#aitcg-tooltip .aitcg-button.apply-but {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: 0 none;
    color: orange;
}
div#aitcg-control-panel .aitcg-button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 26px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 120px;
}
#aitcg-control-panel button:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this will Help. Thanks